# Difference between function(){}.bind(this) and angular.bind(this, function() {})

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the difference between the following codes

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return this.variable;
    }.bind(this), /*...*/);
}
```

and

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function() {
        return this.variable;
    }, /*...*/);
}
```

for me are the same but is there any advantage of using `angular.bind`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in `Function.prototype.bind` function does not exist in older browsers, [such as IE 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility). However, the same syntax can be achieved by using a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill). [This](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L908) is essentially what Angular is doing internally.

The `angular.bind` function does not use `Function.prototype.bind`, so it may be possible to use it in older browsers. Of course, this point is moot if you are using a version of Angular that does not actively support those older browsers.